# What is "Report ID" in Windows Application Error, event 1000 correlated to?

Tags: windows-event-log

I'm analyzing an event 1000 error in a third-party enterprise application which shows a "Faulting module name" of ntdll.dll and wondering: What is the "Report ID" GUID correlated to? and How might I use it to dig further?

Answer (score 2):

The "Report ID" appears to just be a unique identifier which Microsoft assigns to a particular application crash. I do not believe that this value serves any purpose.

To find out more you should look under "View all problem reports", or configure your system to always generate crash dumps in a specified folder (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).